# We're testing advertisements on Personal Finance & Money

Tags: discussion

My name is Juan M and I'm one of the community managers here on the network. You can read more about some of what I'm working on [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312699/new-resources-for-our-stack-exchange-network) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313084/new-resources-for-our-stack-exchange-network-part-2).

For several years we've had [advertising on technology-related sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/263678/1438). But [many of our sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#name) aren't about technology at all, so we haven't sold ads for them. That hasn't been a hardship since Stack Exchange sites require only a small investment from the company to set up and keep live. Thanks entirely to the efforts of your community, this site has become an amazing resource on the internet. Generating revenue from non-technology sites will enable us to dedicate more resources to meeting your needs so this is **good news**.

The test starts May 21 and our advertising team will be monitoring to see how ads are performing. We don't know how many ads will run on this site. It could be just a few or a bit more. In either case, these ads will be carefully vetted and we'll be keeping watch to continue to provide good content.

If you see any ads that are inappropriate or have any questions about this experiment, please let me know by starting a new question and tagging it with [advertisements](/questions/tagged/advertisements). This is a work in progress and we are expecting a time of learning and refinement as we move forward.

Comment: Will you be adding the [setting to disable reduced ads](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273652/choose-to-see-reduced-ads-or-not) to profile pages? Currently I see it in my profile settings on StackOverflow but not here.

Comment: (Now asked as separate question: https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2712/disabling-reduced-ads)

Comment: My comment on this policy is probably of little interest, because I am a new, infrequent, and low-rep user on this site, but I think learning how to ignore ads is of great benefit to healthy personal finance.

Comment: Are ads being selected carefully to avoid promoting products/services that might be contrary to the general philosophy of this site? e.g. ads for payday loans, get-rich-quick schemes, employment scams, speculative gold mining or other specific stocks being pumped, etc.?

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea We have general guidelines for what ads we want to show and which we don't.  However, during this trial period, we're going to experiment and collect metrics (as I've mentioned) so you may or may not see things like what you mentioned.

Comment: @ab2 - sorry, no. Your input is *absolutely* valued here. When you first offered input on a meta question, I noted you are a ~40K SE total rep member. And able to offer as much, if not more to our stack that those of us with only Money.SE rep. Glad you are here.

Comment: @JuanM to be honest I'd be a little concerned if SE was showing some of those kinds of ads anywhere on the network!

Comment: Will there be a way to flag an ad if we think it is inappropriate?

Comment: @DJClayworth If you need to report an ad please take a screenshot of it and send it over to me! jgarza @ stack overflow .com