# Disabling reduced ads

Tags: feature-request

Following the [enabling of advertisements on this site](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2711/were-testing-advertisements-on-personal-finance-money), will you be also enabling the [profile setting to disable reduced ads](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273652/choose-to-see-reduced-ads-or-not)?

Currently I see this setting in my profile settings on StackOverflow, but not here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is something that will not be run while we are in the experiment phase. Once we are able to gather the necessary metrics and data, we can begin the discussion for moving forward with the reduced ads option.

This means that during this initial phase, all users should see the same number of ads until the close of the experiment.